# How I can keep the value of a barButton among the views handled by a tab bar?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

I have two weeks programing in objective-c. Basically, I have a three views handled by a tab bar. Each view has rounded rect buttons that calls another view with different information. Also, at the top of each view, there is a bar button item. The title of all those bar button items depends of the value of a switch: manual or automatic. If it is automatic, the button's title must be "Trigger". If it is manueal, the button's title must be "Star" and, if you make a click on it must change to "Stop". My problem is, the button's title is changing but if I'm in the fist view and I press "start", it change to "stop", but in the second view it's still "start".

So, could you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't understand your problem (it would be easier if you would provide code or pictures). Thus I try to interpret the title of your question:
You have a tab bar controller that controls a few view controllers that have each its own view. These views are independent of each other. If each view has e.g. its own barBottom item but they should all have the same title when you switch from one tab view to another, their titles must be changed by program. Since only the tab bar controller knows when it changes its views, it has to assign the new title to all the barBottom items of its views.
It can do this using its delegate that corresponds to the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol. This delegate (and the tab bar controller may be its own delegate) can e.g. implement the method `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` which is called when one switches from one view to another. In this method, the tab bar controller can set the new title by calling a method in each of its view controllers (which can be accessed via the property `viewControllers`).